# File size limits

Tags: files

i have a text file which its size is 23.5 Mb. i want to reduce file size under 20 Mb. how can i do that?
the file type is: plain text document (text/plain).
this file have ~40000 line and ~500 column.

this is part of file:

```
TRINITY_DN100014_c0_g1  GO:0003674 GO:0003824 GO:0003964 GO:0005488 GO:0016740 GO:0016772 GO:0016779 GO:0034061 GO:0043167 GO:0043169 GO:0046872
TRINITY_DN100015_c0_g1  GO:0000166 GO:0000943 GO:0001882 GO:0001883 GO:0003674 GO:0003676 GO:0003677 GO:0003723 GO:0003824 GO:0003887 GO:0003964 GO:0004175 GO:0004190 GO:0004518 GO:0004519 GO:0004521 GO:0004523 GO:0004540 GO:0005488 GO:0005524 GO:0005575 GO:0005634 GO:0005737 GO:0006139 GO:0006259 GO:0006260 GO:0006278 GO:0006310 GO:0006725 GO:0006807 GO:0008150 GO:0008152 GO:0008233 GO:0008270 GO:0009058 GO:0009059 GO:0009987 GO:0015074 GO:0016032 GO:0016070 GO:0016740 GO:0016772 GO:0016779 GO:0016787 GO:0016788 GO:0016891 GO:0016893 GO:0017076 GO:0018130 GO:0019076 GO:0019438 GO:0030554 GO:0032196 GO:0032197 GO:0032549 GO:0032550 GO:0032553 GO:0032555 GO:0032559 GO:0034061 GO:0034641 GO:0034645 GO:0034654 GO:0035639 GO:0036094 GO:0043167 GO:0043168 GO:0043169 GO:0043170 GO:0043226 GO:0043227 GO:0043229 GO:0043231 GO:0044237 GO:0044238 GO:0044249 GO:0044260 GO:0044271 GO:0044403 GO:0044419 GO:0044422 GO:0044424 GO:0044428 GO:0044446 GO:0044464 GO:0044699 GO:0044763 GO:0044764 GO:0046483 GO:0046872 GO:0046914 GO:0051704 GO:0070001 GO:0070011 GO:0071704 GO:0071897 GO:0090304 GO:0090305 GO:0090501 GO:0097159 GO:0097367 GO:1901265 GO:1901360 GO:1901362 GO:1901363 GO:1901576
TRINITY_DN100018_c0_g1  GO:0005575 GO:0005737 GO:0044424 GO:0044464
TRINITY_DN100019_c0_g1  GO:0003674 GO:0003676 GO:0003723 GO:0005488 GO:0005575 GO:0005681 GO:0006139 GO:0006396 GO:0006397 GO:0006725 GO:0006807 GO:0008150 GO:0008152 GO:0008380 GO:0009987 GO:0016070 GO:0016071 GO:0030529 GO:0032991 GO:0034641 GO:0043170 GO:0044237 GO:0044238 GO:0044260 GO:0044422 GO:0044424 GO:0044428 GO:0044446 GO:0044464 GO:0046483 GO:0071704 GO:0090304 GO:0097159 GO:1901360 GO:1901363
TRINITY_DN100021_c0_g1  GO:0000166 GO:0000902 GO:0000904 GO:0001882 GO:0001883 GO:0003674 GO:0003774 GO:0003777 GO:0003824 GO:0005488 GO:0005524 GO:0005575 GO:0005795 GO:0005871 GO:0005874 GO:0005875 GO:0005886 GO:0006928 GO:0007017 GO:0007018 GO:0008150 GO:0009653 GO:0009987 GO:0010090 GO:0016020 GO:0016043 GO:0016462 GO:0016787 GO:0016817 GO:0016818 GO:0016887 GO:0017076 GO:0017111 GO:0030554 GO:0032502 GO:0032549 GO:0032550 GO:0032553 GO:0032555 GO:0032559 GO:0032989 GO:0032991 GO:0035639 GO:0036094 GO:0043167 GO:0043168 GO:0043234 GO:0044422 GO:0044424 GO:0044430 GO:0044431 GO:0044444 GO:0044446 GO:0044464 GO:0044699 GO:0044763 GO:0044767 GO:0048869 GO:0071840 GO:0097159 GO:0097367 GO:1901265 GO:1901363
```

i changed the file type to csv , html and java by saving as in LiberofficeClac but the new file was bigger than the first.

Comment: gzip/bzip2 ? Perhaps you're not explaining your requirements well enough however...

Comment: You can compress the file (e. g. `gzip filename`) to make it smaller without losing any information, but converting it to other formats (that don't do their own compression) will only make it larger by adding formatting metadata to your data.  `gzip` is a good option because text compresses nicely, and you can still easily access the data through means like `zcat` and `zgrep`.

Comment: compress it using gz or something like that? or replace every `GO:` section of the file with something like `0b10000000` (assuming little endian), using the seventh bit to signal that this character represents three, and the seven 0s representing those characters (`GO:`). the same method can be used for other repeating sequences, such as `00`, by replacing the seven 0s (but keeping the seventh 1 in place). as long as your file stays in ASCII format and doesn't deviate to something like UTF-8, it should work fine (this is known as RLE encoding).

Comment: ^ that's assuming that you have some kind of program you've written to parse the file. if not, then a regular compression program should work fine.

Comment: no i do not want to zip my file, i want to reduce the file size without zip it

Comment: agreed. what do you need the file for?

Comment: i want to upload this file in a web analyzer but it accept only files smaller than 20 Mb

Comment: If you want to reduce the size of the file without compressing it, you need to remove some of the data.  Otherwise you're basically trying to violate the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: My recommendation is that you fix your 'web analyzer' so that it either accepts larger files, or accepts compressed files (auto-decompressing them as required) or both.   Alternatively, if you have no access to fix it yourself, submit a feature-request bug report to whoever is responsible for the analyser.

Comment: BTW, your data looks to be extremely compressible.  A 23MB file containing data like that would compress down to less than 1% of its uncompressed size, even with `gzip`.  `bzip2` would reduce it even further.   e.g. I compressed a 16MB file containing data similar to yours (your sample above repeated about 6000 times) down to 97.3KB with `gzip -9` and 33.3K with `bzip2`.  This would obviously upload in a tiny fraction of the time it takes to upload 23.5MB.

Comment: BTW `xz` compressed the same file down to 7216 bytes.  7.2KB.  That's 0.0441% of the original size.

Comment: @cas impressive! I'll note that for the future :)

Comment: @Joe `xz` took only 3 seconds to compress it too.  `bzip2` took 11 seconds, `gzip -9` was fastest, at only 0.16 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `head -c 20000000` to get the first 20000000 bytes.

Now that you have provided more details on what you want:

- Preserve all the data
- No compression
- Reduce the size

I think it's quite safe to say: That's not possible!

Comment: I think he wants to retain all of the data in the file

Comment: yes i want all of my data in one file

Comment: That wasn't clear from the start.

Comment: Well, if the data contains redundant information, perhaps It could be compressed in a compatible format.  Consider if all those 7digit numbers prefixed by the string `GO:` could be changed.  If the thing that parses it takes a pattern something like the regex `/GO:(\d+)\s/ `then removing the leading zeros from each number would still allow parsing, but might reduce the file size to something under the requested limit.

Comment: But the OP hasn't said anything about the format or the parser, so that's purely speculation.

Comment: OP hasn't said much about anything, which is why everyone is speculating.    Reformatting isn't quite the same as compression, and is certainly less strange than binary techniques

Comment: the analyzer only use text, csv, raw and XML output formats

Comment: when i open my txt file with Liberoffice Calc and save it as xlsx its size rduce to ~12M. but when i save it as csv formt its size increase to ~53 M.